# Telerik Reporting .NET 5 walkthrough yields error "ConfigurationHelper does not exist in current context"

Tags: asp.net-core, telerik-reporting

Following the 'How to Host Reports Service in ASP.NET Core in .NET 5' walk through [here](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/host-the-report-engine-remotely/telerik-reporting-rest-services/asp.net-core-web-api-implementation/host-reports-service-in-.net-5) and early on they have you paste the following in ConfigureSerivces:

```
        // Configure dependencies for ReportsController.
        services.TryAddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
        new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            ReportingEngineConfiguration = ConfigurationHelper.ResolveConfiguration(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()),
            HostAppId = "Net5RestServiceWithCors",
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "Reports"))
        });
```

However **ConfigurationHelper** is flagged as 'does not exist in current context'.

I know I probably need to reference an assembly but I did add all the supposed required dependencies via nuget Telerik.Reporting.Services.AspNetCore.Trial.

So I don't know what assembly I need to get ConfigurationHelper.

I suspect this is a really stupid question because there is virtually nothing on the internet about ConfigurationHelper which means the answer is so simple people don't even need to google it.

So what do I need to add to a brand new ASP.NET Core Web Application 5.0 with nuget Telerik.Reporting.Services.AspNetCore.Trial in order to resolve ConfigurationHelper?

Comment: Turns out to be a non-problem since the walk through later removes the offending line and replaces it without the ConfigurationHelper. The original question however is still valid: where is this defined?

Answer (score 2):

**ConfigurationHelper** is just a static class in your project, you can rename it if you want, then use it in this line `ReportingEngineConfiguration = ConfigurationHelper.ResolveConfiguration(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()),`

Taken from the article you have posted:

```
static class ConfigurationHelper
    {
        public static IConfiguration ResolveConfiguration(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            var reportingConfigFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "appsettings.json");
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(reportingConfigFileName, true)
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

You can have a look at the demo projects in your installation, the path should be similar to C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R2 2022\Examples\CSharp.NET 5\ReportingRestServiceCorsDemo

Comment: Awesome. As I said probably a dumb question.